# How does Mozilla create this animated effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

On its release notes to Firefox 42, Mozilla has an animation effect that uses no Javascript, no CSS animation, no video or plug-in, and no animated gif.

Please refer to [this page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/42.0/whatsnew/?oldversion=41.0.2) to observe the effect. There is a robot at the bottom right corner of the shield that blinks every few seconds. It is in a `div` element of class `critter bottom-right`

How is this effect done?

EDIT: I was mistaken; CSS animations are used; they just don't show up in the `Animations` tab of the DOM Inspector but they can be seen in the `Rules` tab when `::before` `::after` is selected within the div element containing the robot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the area and "Inspect Element"

Inside `<div class="shield-container></div>` you can see the following css animation

[image]

See the CSS section of the debug tools to see what css does there.

[image]

Comment: How do you get to the CSS section of the debug tool? I see the same thing you posted above, but when I select the Animations tab within the console, there are no animations: [my screenshot](http://snag.gy/X7xA4.jpg)

Comment: Select `::before` or `::after`. CSS is listed under rules. I will update my answer.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. When I didn't see anything in the animations tab, and that it worked even with JavaScript disabled and without a video tag, I thought it was magic.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It uses CSS animation. You can see the animation rule in the DOM inspector.

[image: Screen capture of CSS]

Comment: I probably need to learn how to use Inspector. I checked it and it doesn't show me any animation. See my [screenshot](http://snag.gy/X7xA4.jpg).  How did you get this screenshot?

Comment: I clicked on the right thing in the DOM inspector. Look at the selector in it. It ends in `::after`. You're two lines too high in the element selector pane.

Comment: Selecting `::before` or `::after` makes not difference for me. [See?](http://snag.gy/rQiRu.jpg).  That's why I originally thought CSS animations were not used

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't show up in the animation pane for some reason. It's in the rules pane.

Comment: Got it. That threw me for a loop. Thanks. Wish I could select 2 answers. Charlie updated his to be more thorough so I went with that.

Answer (score 1):

This uses CSS animation on the :before pseudo element.

```
#tracking-protection-animation .critter.bottom-right::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 52px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-image: url("/media/img/firefox/tracking-protection/sheild-animation/eye-lid-bottom-right.070dfe3825e1.png");
    opacity: 0;
    content: "";
    animation: 6s linear 0s normal none infinite running blink;
}
@keyframes blink{
    0%{
        opacity:0
    }

    40%{
        opacity:0
    }

    41%{
        opacity:1
    }

    42%{
        opacity:1
    }

    43%{
        opacity:0
    }

    75%{
        opacity:0
    }

    76%{
        opacity:1
    }

    77%{
        opacity:1
    }

    78%{
        opacity:0
    }

    100%{
        opacity:0
    }
```

Comment: where do you find the animation? In Inspector when I hover over the div, I don't see any: [screenshot](http://snag.gy/X7xA4.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CSS and mark-up to reproduce the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ren8tx55/

```
<div id="tracking-protection-animation">
    <div class="shield-container">
        <div class="critter top-left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tracking-protection-animation .shield-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

#tracking-protection-animation .critter.top-left::before {
    animation: 7s linear 0s normal none infinite running blink;
    background-image: url("https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/firefox/tracking-protection/sheild-animation/eye-lid-top-right.8fb9f328fa1f.png");
    content: "";
    height: 48px;
    left: 45px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 56px;
    width: 48px;
}
#tracking-protection-animation .critter.top-left::after {
    animation: 10s linear 0s normal none infinite running recorder;
    background-color: #ff397e;
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: "";
    height: 8px;
    left: 24px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 76px;
    width: 8px;
}
#tracking-protection-animation .critter.top-left {
    background-image: url("https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net//media/img/firefox/tracking-protection/sheild-animation/critter-top-left.e4cd620eeb90.png");
    height: 129px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 122px;
}
#tracking-protection-animation .critter {
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes recorder {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
}
20% {
    opacity: 0;
}
21% {
    opacity: 1;
}
80% {
    opacity: 1;
}
81% {
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
}
}
@keyframes blink {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
}
40% {
    opacity: 0;
}
41% {
    opacity: 1;
}
42% {
    opacity: 1;
}
43% {
    opacity: 0;
}
75% {
    opacity: 0;
}
76% {
    opacity: 1;
}
77% {
    opacity: 1;
}
78% {
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
}
}
```